# Como fazer uma função dentro de uma função retornar um vetor?

Tags: c, array, matriz

Tenho um trabalho para o meu curso, e é necessário fazer um programa similar ao jogo da megasena. Está quase pronto, mas estou encontrando um pequeno problema e preciso de ajuda.

 Dados do trabalho: máximo de 10 jogadores podem apostar, cada um pode apostar de 6 até 15 números no intervalo [1,60].

Na função `sorteiaNumerosSena()`, faço o sorteio de 6 números aleatórios e os aloco em um vetor de 6 posições. Esta função está dentro da função `pegaApostasJogadores()`. Quero retornar o vetor `numerosApostas[]` para a função e utilizá-lo em outra função para ser exibido e comparado com as apostas dos jogadores. Não estou conseguindo retornar este vetor. Alguém poderia me indicar uma solução ou um método melhor para solucionar isto? O código completo encontra-se logo abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int pegaNumeroJogadores (); // Protótipo
int validaNumeroJogadores (int numeroJogadores); // Protótipo
int pegaApostasJogadores (int qtdeJogadores); // Protótipo
int validaQuantidadeApostas (int quantidadeApostas); // Protótipo
int validaApostaJogador (int apostaDoJogador); // Protótipo
int sorteiaNumerosSena (); // Protótipo
int mostraApostas (int contadorLinha, int contadorColuna, int apostasJogadores[][14], int *vetorApostas, int qtdeJogadores); // Protótipo
int verificaGanhador (int contadorLinha, int contadorColuna, int apostasJogadores[][14], int *vetorApostas, int qtdeJogadores, int *sorteados); // Protótipo

int main (void) {
    // Declarações locais
        int qtdeJogadores;
    // Instruções
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
        qtdeJogadores = pegaNumeroJogadores();
        pegaApostasJogadores(qtdeJogadores);
        return 0;
}

int pegaNumeroJogadores () {
    // Declarações locais
        int numeroJogadores;
    // Instruções
        printf("Insira a quantidade de jogadores\n> ");
        scanf("%d", &numeroJogadores);
        numeroJogadores = validaNumeroJogadores(numeroJogadores);
        return numeroJogadores;
}

int validaNumeroJogadores (int numeroJogadores) {
    // Declarações locais
    // Instruções
        while ((numeroJogadores <= 0) || (numeroJogadores > 10)) {
            printf("Quantidade inválida de jogadores, insira novamente.\n> ");
            scanf("%d", &numeroJogadores);
        }
        return numeroJogadores;
}

int pegaApostasJogadores (int qtdeJogadores) {
    // Declarações locais
        int contadorColuna, contadorLinha, quantidadeApostas, apostaDoJogador, vetorApostas[9], apostasJogadores[9][14], sorteados;
    // Instruções
        for (contadorLinha = 0; contadorLinha < qtdeJogadores; contadorLinha++) {
            printf("Jogador de número %d, quantos números jogará?\n> ", contadorLinha+1);
            scanf("%d", &quantidadeApostas);
            vetorApostas[contadorLinha] = quantidadeApostas;
            for (contadorColuna = 0; contadorColuna < quantidadeApostas; contadorColuna++) {
                printf("%dº número da aposta: ", contadorColuna+1);
                scanf("%d", &apostaDoJogador);
                apostaDoJogador = validaApostaJogador(apostaDoJogador); /* Valida a aposta do jogador */
                apostasJogadores[contadorLinha][contadorColuna] = apostaDoJogador;
            }           
        }
        system("cls");
        sorteados = sorteiaNumerosSena();
        printf("%d\n", sorteados);
        mostraApostas(contadorLinha,contadorColuna,apostasJogadores,vetorApostas,qtdeJogadores);
        verificaGanhador(contadorLinha,contadorColuna,apostasJogadores,vetorApostas,qtdeJogadores,sorteados);
}

int validaQuantidadeApostas (int quantidadeApostas) {
    // Declarações locais
    // Instruções
       while ((quantidadeApostas < 6) || (quantidadeApostas > 15)) {
             printf("Quantidade de apostas inválida, favor inserir outra.\n> ");
             scanf("%d", &quantidadeApostas);
       }
       return quantidadeApostas;
}

int validaApostaJogador (int apostaDoJogador) {
    // Declarações locais
    // Instruções
        while ((apostaDoJogador <= 0) || (apostaDoJogador > 60)) {
            printf("Sua aposta é inválida, favor utilizar outra.\n> ");
            scanf("%d", &apostaDoJogador);
        }
        return apostaDoJogador;
}

int sorteiaNumerosSena () {
    // Declarações locais
       static int numerosSorteio[6];
       int contador, auxiliar, troca;
    // Instruções
       printf("SORTEIO DE 6 NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS\n");
       srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
       for (contador = 1; contador <= 6; contador++) {
           numerosSorteio[contador] = (1+rand()%60);
           for (auxiliar = 1; auxiliar <= contador; auxiliar++) {
               if (numerosSorteio[auxiliar] == numerosSorteio[contador]) {
                  numerosSorteio[contador] = (1+rand()%60);
               }
           }
       }
       for (contador = 1; contador <= 6; contador++) {
           for (auxiliar = contador+1; auxiliar <= 6; auxiliar++) {
               if (numerosSorteio[contador] > numerosSorteio[auxiliar]) {
                  troca = numerosSorteio[auxiliar];
                  numerosSorteio[auxiliar] = numerosSorteio[contador];
                  numerosSorteio[contador] = troca;

               }
           }
           //printf("Números sorteados: %d\n", numerosSorteio[contador]);  
       }
}

int mostraApostas (int contadorLinha, int contadorColuna, int apostasJogadores[][14], int *vetorApostas, int qtdeJogadores) {
        // Instruções
        for (contadorLinha = 0; contadorLinha < qtdeJogadores; contadorLinha++) {
            printf("Apostas do %dº jogador: ", contadorLinha+1);
            for (contadorColuna = 0; contadorColuna < vetorApostas[contadorLinha]; contadorColuna++) {
                printf("%d ", apostasJogadores[contadorLinha][contadorColuna]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int verificaGanhador (int contadorLinha, int contadorColuna, int apostasJogadores[][14], int *vetorApostas, int qtdeJogadores, int *sorteados) {
    // Declarações locais
        int contador, acertos;
    // Instruções
        for (contadorLinha = 0; contadorLinha < qtdeJogadores; contadorLinha++) {
            for (contadorColuna = 0; contadorColuna < vetorApostas[contadorLinha]; contadorColuna++) {
                for (contador = 1; contador <= 6; contador++) { 
                    if (apostasJogadores[contadorLinha][contadorColuna] == sorteados[contador]) {
                        acertos++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (acertos == 6) {
                printf("Jogador %d, você acertou os 6 números! És o novo milionário nacional!!\n", contadorLinha+1);
            }
            else {
                printf("Jogador %d, você obteve %d acertos.\n", contadorLinha+1,acertos);
            }
        }       
}
```

Comment: Uma nota engraçada: parece que de ambos os lados do Atlântico um dos primeiros programas que se faz é sempre o da lotaria/mega sena/euromilhões :)

Comment: **ATENÇÃO:** em C os arrays são indexados de `0` a `n - 1`. No teu código estás a indexar de `1` a `n` e, portanto, desperdiçando 1 elemento e acedendo a a outro elemento que não existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em C não é possivel passar um array directamente como resultado de uma função. Terá que devolver um ponteiro para o array criado.

Exemplo:

```
int* DevolveArray()
{
    int arrayExemplo[5];
    return arrayExemplo;
}
```

**No entanto** o código acima tem um problema. Como o array é criado localmente, quando o ponteiro for devolvido e utilizado pela função que invocou `DevolveArray(...)`, a memória para onde o ponteiro aponta pode já não ser o `array`. Isto acontece porque o `array` foi criado na `stack` e quando saimos de `DevolveArray(...)` o espaço ocupado pelo `array` pode agora ser reaproveitado por outras funções.

**Como resolver a questão então?**

Uma forma é criar um array estático dentro da função e devolver um ponteiro para esse array:

```
int* DevolveArray()
{
    static int arrayExemplo[5];
    return arrayExemplo;
}
```

O problema desta aproximação é que desta forma o `array` torna-se global, isto é, todas as chamadas a `DevolveArray(...)` vão usar o mesmo bloco de memória, o que pode levar a valores inesperados no `array` (entre outras).

Assim, uma outra forma de resolver a questão será criar um bloco de memória dinamicamente dentro de `DevolveArray(...)` e devolver um ponteiro para o `array` criado:

```
int* DevolveArray(int nTamanhoArray)
{
    int* pArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * nTamanhoArray);
    return pArray;
}
```

Desta forma, cada chamada para `DevolveArray(...)` vai criar um bloco de memória novo (i.e um array novo). Convém notar que tem de ter atenção à *lifetime* do `array`, isto é, garantir que a memória é libertada quando já não é precisa (caso contrário, existe o risco de criar *memory leaks*):

```
free(pArray); // chamar a função free com o ponteiro do array criado.
```

Por ultimo, de forma a encapsular o *lifetime* do `array` num único sítio pode optar por criar o `array` e passá-lo por ponteiro para a função que o vai manipular/alterar:

```
void ModArray(int* pArray, int nSizeArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nSizeArray; ++i)
    {
        *(pArray + i) = i;
    }
}

void ConsomeArray()
{
    int nSize = 10;
    int* pArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * nSize);
    ModArray(pArray, nSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < nSizeArray; ++i)
    {
        printf("ID %d: %d", i, *(pArray + i));
    }

    free(pArray);
}
```

Desta forma garante que o *lifetime* do `array` fica localizado numa na função `ConsomeArray(...)` que fica responsável por criar e libertar a memória conforme necessário.